# Site Content and Structure data move limits?

Tags: 2007, document-library, content-and-structure

I'm attempting to split a large library of approx 8,000 items into 4 seperate folders in the same (current) library.

Each group of 2,000 items will be 1GB+.

Are there limits to how much data can be transferred using site content and structure? Will it time out?

Note: This is pertaining to MOSS 2007

Answer (score 1):

This Technet document gives details on the limitations (& effects on performance) for SharePoint 2007 document libraries - [Plan for software boundaries.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28office.12%29.aspx)

As stated in the above link - a document library can have 5 million per library (using nested folders, standard views & site hiearchy). The limitations to occurs due to the number of items per view (at ~2000). So customization of views may be needed.

Here's a summary of the limitations - [SharePoint 2007 Maximum Limits](https://sharepoint.missouri.edu/wiki/Wiki%20Pages/SharePoint%202007%20Maximum%20Limits.aspx).

**UPDATE:** One can use the SharePoint 2007 feature of ['Work with site content and structure'](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=134) to handle the files. I recollect encountering performance degradation as the number of nested folders increase (i.e, deeper site hiearchy are more prone to performance issues). Regarding time-outs - it would vary based on your environment and the file-types and the number of files (some test runs may help - for e.g., a target folder at a time). There are commercial tools that can help with the migration and also one can develop scripts to do the same.

Comment: Thanks @SB-Chatterjee but that's not really what I asked. I'm asking how much data can be **transferred** using the site content and structure tool. I'm already aware of the limits, that's why I'm trying to split the libraries/lists.

Comment: I have updated my response above.

Answer (score 0):

Max allowed is 2GB per item, it should not time out.

Instead of doing using Site content and Structure, you can do it by opening the list with the **Windows Explorer** and transfer the data which is easy and fast process.

Comment: I agree, I would use Windows Explorer View